# ExpressionEngine 5 -Maximum number of entries

Tags: entries, ee5

In previous versions of EE, there was a setting in the Channels called "Maximum number of entries". However, in EE5 I can't find this setting- is it still available?

Answer (score 3):

Yep it is still there.  Go to `Developer/Channels` and edit a channel (or create a new one) - the Maximum number of entries value is the third setting field down on the "Channel" tab (i.e. the first one that appears when you edit a channel).

More in the [EE documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/channels.html#channel-tab).

[image]

HTH

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I kept missing that.